# Not finding request id in aws cloud trail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail

I am trying to debug a pipeline failing one of its action with an error 403.
I am reaching cloud trail to find more detail about the action, but I can not find the event linked to the request. When I search in cloud trail for the request id, it gives me nothing.

I am in only one region and only one account.

I believe all action are supposed to be log into cloud trail, specially the one with error, am I wrong?
Do I need to configure some service to actually turn on event sent to cloud trail?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

CloudTrail is not a tool used for troubleshooting. Essentially it's an auditing tool that records changes to resources in your AWS accounts.

What is your pipeline built on? If it's on CodePipeline, you should be able to view the details on the console, and you can configure to send the pipeline logs to CloudWatch. Additionally, CloudTrail should record the API calls made by CodePipeline as well, although it may not be detailed enough to actually troubleshoot an error - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/monitoring-cloudtrail-logs.html